# Android: Ways about having a "Level Complete" dialog box in a layout

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm making a game and when the user wins, I want to have a dialog box show up like this:

[image: http://gm-cdn.gamezebo.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/a/tips-medium-11345-1366820257.png]

I am new to android programming, and I was wondering what the best way of going about doing this.

Things I have thought about so far:

- Creating a canvas and drawing it (but I'm using a Layout)
- Using a dialog (but these seems like you can't customize the color/texture)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your requirement fullfill using creating custom dialog.simple you create layout.xml file for your dialog.and call from your requirment:

```
    Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    mDialog.show();
```

more for custom dialog:http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111